# I need <h1> tag for good SEO report on my webpage. What happen when I have none?

Tags: html, css, seo

I have webpage where I use only img tag instead of h1 tag.
So Image is instead heading and is just simple web.
But because of that I don't get good SEO report.
What can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: That's not hwy you have SEO issues.

Comment: @John why does SO have a tag for SEO if it's off-topic?

Comment: seo also work with image's alt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have place for "real" H1 with text, you can use something like this:

```
<h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="PAGE TITLE">
</h1>
```

SEO-wise, it's still interpreted as `<h1>PAGE TITLE</h1>`.

Comment: OP don't want to use h1 tag....

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me. Now I have better SEO report.